# Cloud Run / Docker loading large files for ML prediction

Tags: python, docker, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to serve a fairly large model (1GB) from a `Flask` powered docker container on Google Cloud Run.

I am trying to figure out the best way load the `pickle` / `joblib` model files - so as to reduce container start up time.

Since including in the github source is not an option or desired, the only idea I have now is to try and read it into the container from the `Dockerfile` by using `gsutil`.

How would this affect cold container startup time? Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Also it seems that calling `joblib.load(model_file_path)` in the code is not a good idea - as the load can take 30 secs or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation is to build the container with the model inside it. You win 2 things like this:

- At startup, you don't have to download the file (you save startup time)
- You don't have to store the model (for information, the file are stored in /tmp directory which is a in memory file system, and thus you use memory space in your instance) and thus to increase the required memory (you save money, and the planet!)

I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/portable-prediction-with-tensorflow-and-cloud-run-669c1c73ebd1)

However, loading a 1Gb model will take time. A feature is coming (min instance, that keep a minimal number of instance warm, to prevent cold start, but it's not free!)

Comment: Would you mind please adding a snippet to show how to copy the model from GCS into the container?

Comment: Do you means to create a container with the model already in it? Like this, at runtime, the container start with the container already downloaded. correct?

Comment: When calling `gcloud builds` the Dockerfile should have a command within it - which pulls the model file from GCS into the container so it will be available for serving. Since the containers is built via Github actions the model is not available from a local file system.

Comment: @dendog Your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64969644/copy-files-from-gcs-into-a-cloud-run-docker-container-during-build) is related to this?

Comment: Indeed it is :)

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Run has an in memory file system, to download or use a 1GB file, you need to ensure you have picked enough memory for your instances. Try using `4GiB`, see the [docs to set memory limits](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits)